# Javascript - Rounding Issue with Ints?

Tags: javascript, rounding-error

The prompt: 
Given a list of coin values in **denominations**, what is the minimum amount of coins needed to return **amount**?  If it's not possible, return -1.

I believe I wrote a working solution provided below.  However, when running through the test cases, my solution kept on returning **different** numbers each time!!  The answer was either correct, or off by 1.

I really don't understand why, as I think all values are integers and I used "parseInt" and even "round" on every value but was still off by 1.

```
const solution = (denominations, amount) => {

  denominations.sort(function(a,b){
    return a-b; 
  }); 

  var count = 0; 
  var amountLeft = amount;

  for(var i = denominations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        var curNum = denominations[i];
    while(amountLeft >= curNum){
      amountLeft = amountLeft - curNum;
      count ++; 
    }
  }

  console.log(amountLeft); 
  console.log(count); 

  if(amountLeft > 0) return -1; 
  return count; 
};


solution(
[2, 7, 11, 18, 14, 17, 12, 16, 9, 15, 3, 19],
4033
);
```

Comment: change ` count ++; `  to ` count++; `  with no space inside

Comment: big function is => small function not => sort((a,b)=>b-a)

Comment: I copied your code into https://jsfiddle.net/ and it's reliably logging 0 and 214.  So in what sense is it returning different numbers each time?

Comment: Hi @user2740650  if you run the code on a variety of inputs, for other inputs where it's possible to return exact change with "denominations" (thus amountLeft should be 0 at the end), it might log 1 for amountLeft and therefore return -1 as output.

Comment: When you said "kept on returning different numbers each time" that makes it seem like the same inputs will randomly cause different output.  But I think you're saying that your code has a bug.  If so, you probably just need to do some debugging.  At the very least, provide a simple example where you're getting the wrong result.  It sounds like you're asking us to experiment and find the cases where it doesn't work.